# How to implement background service while loading a listview?

Tags: android-service

2 screens are present in one application ,
In first screen only one button is there and in the 2nd screen 1000 list items in a single list , if user clicks on button in the 1st screen he will directs to 2nd screen but in the 2nd screen 1000 list items are present for loading these 1000 list items it takes long time so user clicks on menu button and go to some other application , after some time user is back to main application then list view is in previous state i.e still loading , i would like to resolve this by using service implementation in the background , is it possible in android ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can run a background process using threads, async task , services
but for UIupdating UIthread is best process because

```
When your app performs intensive work in response to user interaction, this single thread model can yield poor performance unless you implement your application properly. Specifically, if everything is happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From the user's perspective, the application appears to hang. Even worse, if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog. The user might then decide to quit your application and uninstall it if they are unhappy.

Additionally, the Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread. Thus, there are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:

Do not block the UI thread Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread**
```